# Sound drivers corrupted after Windows update

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-update

So yesterday my Laptop (Dell Inspiron 15-3567) was working properly. When I was shutting it down, Windows 10 started doing some updates. Today, I power on my laptop and what do I see? This :

[image]

And when I went to Device Manager I saw this :

[image]

I've searched a bit and tried too many things, none of them worked. I tried uninstalling the drivers then restarting, I've tried updating the drivers (from Device Manager), I've tried restarting the audio services, I've tried doing a system restore from a few days ago...

How can I fix this?

PS. The update came from the last Windows Insider Slow Programme I'm signed in and I've also tried uninstalling the update.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest downloading and installing the
[Dell Update Application](https://www.dell.com/support/home/si/en/sibsdt1/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3567-laptop/drivers)
for your model.

As the date of the application is very recent, it may find compatible drivers
for your computer.

As another advice, I suggest avoiding the Windows Insider Program, if you only wish
tested software to be installed on the computer.